# How does the "Accept Files" option for MFC dialog controls work?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

MFC dialog controls such as IP Controls and Edit Controls have an option under behavior to "Accept Files." Where does the file "go" once dropped on the control? Visual Studio doesn't appear to have an event handler for file dropping; can I add one manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls that have this style receive [WM_DROPFILES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/wm-dropfiles) notification. They receive a handle to an internal structure describing the dropped files. Pass this handle to DragFinish, DragQueryFile, or DragQueryPoint to retrieve information about the dropped files.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Where is the notification received - is there an built-in listener of some kind? How do I pass the handle like you suggested?

Comment: It's a normal message like WM_CLOSE, WM_CREATE etc. Since you are using MFC, you can use a [Message Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-maps-mfc?view=vs-2019) The HDROP handle is passed as a message parameter.

Comment: I think you've pointed me in the right direction. Thanks for the help!